mariadb container via docker-compose not accessible from outside via ip/hostname
version: "3"

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
    links:
      - mariadb
    expose:
      - 6969
    ports:
      - "6969:6969"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    restart: always

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11.8
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

when i build with this docker-compose the app can see the database and interact with it, but i cannot access the db with dbeaver or similar applications over the internet, how do i expose the database so that i can connect to it via dbeaver or directly over the internet.
this is the error:
Could not connect to myip here:3306 : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Please clarify "from the outside". Have you configured port forwarding on your router? In general, you shouldn't expose databases over the open internet

i do mean over the internet, the docker-compose is running on my vps and i want to access it via my own network via dbeaver or something, is there a better way to set this up without exposing it directly? thanks.

Your VPS probably has firewall settings you'll have to configure to allow connections to certain ports and addresses

thing is I could connect to it when i simply ran it via docker, its with docker-compose and after i added the "networks" field I think that the problem started happening.
is there some option I have to add here or this should be working?

Docker Compose creates a default network bridge if you don't set it. I don't think that's the issue

I see, i'll keep looking in the firewall settings maybe its something there. thanks.

You can alternatively run a container like phpmyadmin, then expose that over the internet. But if port 6969 works, there's no reason 3306 shouldn't connect
